# Flutter for Web: text cut off at bottom on Android Chrome

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a Web app through Flutter and when I tried to check my web app with Android simulator's browser, bottom part of the text cuts off. This can be related to lineSpacingMultiplier or LinearLayouts. But I'm not sure how to fix this with Flutter for Web. I don't have any physical Android device. Any help is appreciated!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
          child: Text(
        'good',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check padding...

Comment: paste your code for a better understanding.

Comment: it's not related to padding, I found temporary solution which add height for text.

Comment: @user12208004 could you please post your temporary solution here?

Comment: add height like this on your Text 
          style: TextStyle(
            height: 1.5,
          ),

Comment: height:1.5 will not match the original size, use height:1. Thank you for posting the solution, this seems to be a bug in flutter web

Answer (score 0):

add: height: 1.5 fix my problem.

```
Text(
                    widget.item.name + '\n' ?? '',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: MColors.primaryDarkBlue,
                      fontSize: titleFontSize,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      height: 1.5,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 2,
                  )
```